# Need to display parent's field values in child layout

Tags: object, page-layout

I am new to Salesforce and need suggestions for a requirement which I am facing.

I have few fields present in the parent object and have a requirement wherein I need to display them in child object layout.The values should be populated on load of child layout page.
Please suggest.

Comment: What about a formula field?

Answer (score 2):

On the child object, create Formula fields, and in the formula put the value of ParenRelationShipName.FieldName
for example if you want to display the account(parent) name on the contact(child)
the you'd create a formula on the contact with the following value in the formula:

```
Account.Name
```

Salesforce.com helps you getting those values by providing a lookup in the formula, here's a screenshot of how to pull that up
[image: Parent Child Formula sample]

And this is how the formula will look like:

[image: formula result]